# Postgresql 14 on Windows 10: pg_ctl.exe returns is not a database cluster directory

Tags: postgresql, installation, windows-10

I have installed postgresql 14 on a Windows 10 machine. But, I'm getting this message:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
> pg_ctl.exe start -D "C:\postgres"
pg_ctl: directory "C:/postgres" is not a database cluster directory
```

The installation log file at `%temp%\install-postgresql.log` shows this text at the very end:

> Error running C:\WINDOWS\System32\cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\14/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT
> AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****"
> "C:\Users\nephewtom\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_80ce3934c2"
> "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data"
> 5432 "DEFAULT" 0: Program ended with an error exit code Problem
> running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
> The database cluster initialisation failed. Setting variable whoami
> from C:\WINDOWS\System32\whoami  Script exit code: 0

I suspect it may be due to a permissions issue.

Checking the troubleshoot guide [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Running_%26_Installing_PostgreSQL_On_Native_Windows#I.27m_getting_permissions_errors_when_installing.2Frunning_initdb), it suggests to use `cscript.exe`, but that failed.

Comment: If the installer failed to run `initdb`, run it manually. You may also want to run `pg_ctl register` with the appropriate options to create a Windows service.

Comment: Yes, that made it, thank you very much @LaurenzAlbe !

Comment: By the way, when creating a Windows service :
`.\pg_ctl.exe register -D c:\PostgreSQL\14\data -N postgresql -U nephewtom -P nephewtom -S auto -e postgresql ` 

`pg_ctl: could not register service "postgresql": error code 1057`

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the required permissions, or there is already a service with that name.

Comment: Maybe you could try a binary install - if that can suit your needs?

Comment: @Vérace What do you mean by binary install?

Comment: @nephewtom - try here: https://www.enterprisedb.com/download-postgresql-binaries! :-)

Comment: Well, I suspect that won't solve the `pg_ctl.exe register` issue, which seems like a problem in the required permissions for my user. My company manages that, and it is out of my control for the moment, and working fine with current installation. Anyway, thank you for the suggestion. I might try it at some point.

Answer (score 3):

@LaurenzAlbe comment made it.
He deserves all the credit, but I am posting the answer with commands output in case somebody has the same issue and it could help.

First, running `initdb.exe` :

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin> .\initdb.exe -D c:/PostgreSQL/14/data
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "nephewtom".  
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "English_United States.1252".  
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "WIN1252".  
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".  

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory c:/PostgreSQL/14/data ... ok  
creating subdirectories ... ok  
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... windows   
selecting default max_connections ... 100   
selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB  
selecting default time zone ... Europe/Paris  
creating configuration files ... ok  
running bootstrap script ... ok  
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok  
syncing data to disk ... ok  

initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    ".\pg_ctl" -D "c:\PostgreSQL\14\data\\" -l logfile start
```

Then starting PostgreSQL with `pg_ctl.exe` :

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin> .\pg_ctl.exe start -D c:\PostgreSQL\14\data  
waiting for server to start....  
2022-03-14 13:13:34.114 CET [1972] LOG: starting PostgreSQL 14.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit  
2022-03-14 13:13:34.126 CET [1972] LOG: listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432  
2022-03-14 13:13:34.126 CET [1972] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432  
2022-03-14 13:13:34.219 CET [26212] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-03-14 13:13:01 CET    
2022-03-14 13:13:34.485 CET [1972] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections  
done 
server started
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what went wrong with your installation.
But I am pretty sure that `"C:\postgres"` is not the [directory of your configuration files](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pg-ctl.html). That would be: `"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data"`.
(Should be the same as `%postgresql_dir%\data`.) So:

```
pg_ctl.exe start -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data"
```

Comment: I had already tried that and got the same error.